# Creating dynamic SASS variable to change Ionic 2 tab menu?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, sass

I'm looking for changing the color of my tab menu in Ionic 2 project, getting a value from backend (type string, like: '#ebebeb').

`<ion-tab>` tag have the attribute `[color]=""` which get the value from "variables.scss" sass file.

In variables.scss we can find:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  custom: #ebebeb
);
```

I added the variable "custom" with my color.

Ok, now, I want to know if it's possible to make dynamic this variable "custom". I'm reading the string from backend (http request) in Angular 2 typescript, so I have the global variable "colorString", but I want to know if I can change this SASS variable "custom" and push it dynamically the colorString variable.

I've read that it's impossible to do that, but I want to know your opinion, maybe with jQuery?

Greetings ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant modify the sass variable on the fly. But if you want to modify styles dynamically based on a value from the back-end then be ready to get your hands dirty with javascript.

This is not exactly a very graceful way of doing it but :

```
<ion-tab [ngStyle]="getStyleFromBg()" ></ion-tab>
```

In your ts file :

```
variable : any;
In constructor : get the string from backend & store to variable

getStyleFromBg(){
    if(variable)
         return "background-color : "+variable; // replace background-color with the style attribute
    else
        return "";
}
```

Once again, this is not a very elegant solution & I would suggest not to do it this dynamically.

A better way to do it is to have a bunch of sass variable with these color codes & just get from back-end which one of these color codes you would want to use. That woud be a better way to do it.

Comment: Building on this, you could easily add [ngStyle]="{'color': colorString}" to your html to get the custom color added to whatever element you want. But like Bala Abhinav stated, you cannot modify sass on the fly, its processed into regular css.